# How do I increase the storage for my stimpacks and radaways?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, what is the proper way to increase the storage space for stimpacks and radaways?

I have reached a 15 stimpack cap with any further production being discared. The storage room itself doesn't mention stats for stimpack storage cap.  The Medbay does have a stat for stimpack storage but it labeled as "10" which is not my observed cap.

So, should I:

1. Upgrade my storage room?
2. Add a second storage room?
3. Upgrade my medbay?
4. Add a second medbay?
5. Something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Their storage is directly tied to the number of rooms that produce them you have. Each room will increase the storage.

They are Not affected by the 'storage' room or upgrading the rooms that produce them.

This information can be read in the in-game guide on page 16 (Storage)

Comment: Whats a good strategy to use? I produce more stimpacks than I can store. I send a random person to wastelands when its full. If I build a lot of empty medbays, then they will just eat more of my power. What to do?

Comment: @Esq You are doing what you can do basically.. They cant be sold or used for anything other than healing your dwellers and extending the time a wanderer can be out in the wasteland. Eventually you will get to the point where adding in more medbays will not be as big of a hit.. but thats generally after you get the upgraded reactors.. But at the end of the day.. what else do you have to do in Fallout Shelter? :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the in-game guide (page 17):

- Building MedBays and Science Labs will increase the number of Stimpaks and RadAways you can store.

Every MedBay built increases your Stimpak storage by 10. You begin the game with a capacity of 5.

Upgrading MedBays only increases its performance (page 16); it has nothing to do with storage capacity.

Storage rooms only increase storage for dweller's weapons and outfits.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the nice guide (page 16) there is in the game](http://falloutsheltermanual.com/21pagefalloutsheltermanual/), only merging the medbay will give you more inventory space for Stimpacks.